# de JavaScript para jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom eu tenho uma dúvida sobre **jQuery**, como ficaria o seguinte código **JavaScript Puro** usando o **jQuery**?

```js
function writeTotal(value){
    var total = document.getElementById('total');
    total.innerHTML = floatToMoneyText(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma reduzida:

```
function writeTotal(value) {
    $('#total').html(floatToMoneyText(value));
}
```

Esse `floatToMoneyText` provavelmente também poderia ser convertido para jQuery, mas teria que saber o que você faz exatamente nele

Answer (score 1):

E que tal testar o parâmetro **value** para ver se o mesmo é nulo/vazio:

```
function writeTotal(value) {

var innerHtml = "";

if (value === window.undefined || value === null || value === "") {
    innerHtml = "R$ 0,00";
}
else {
    innerHtml = floatToMoneyText(value);
}

$('#total').html(innerHtml);
};
```

Comment: O corpo da função poderia ser trocado por `$('#total').html(value ? floatToMoneyText(value) : "R$ 0,00");`, porém acho que isso seria responsabilidade da função `floatToMoneyText`

Comment: **Claro!** usar uma **condição ternária** é uma boa, particularmente eu gosto de verificar se é nulo ou vazio, fica mais fácil para a leitura humana. Também concordo, criar uma validação dentro da função **floatToMoneyText**.